# Adding versus ORing performance

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, compiler-optimization, addition

I have seen people use addition where a bitwise OR would be more conceptually appropriate, because they believe it is faster.  Is this true?  If yes, do all modern compilers know this trick?

Comment: If anything, I would expect the `OR` instruction to be faster than the `ADD` instruction.  There is less logic involved to perform the instructions.

Comment: @Jeff M: It's inappropriate to make a claim like that without actually measuring the performance. Addition is very fast. So is logical or.

Comment: @Greg: It wasn't really meant to be a claim for whatever is faster - I agree, you should always test to know for sure - it was just to address what the "other people" thought as it went against everything I knew.  If you know the how the hardware works, it would be obvious which is generally faster so I shared what I would have expected.  Just wanted to point that out.

Comment: I would agree.  I would expect OR and ADD to be the same speed on a modern CPU, but mathematically, performing an OR operation on a bitstring is not as complex as performing an ADD operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Conceptually appropriate" and "faster" are two different things.  The former is semantics, while the latter often involves breaking semantics.

As for the question in the title, there's very little (if any) difference speedwise.  A compiler for a CPU where this actually happens, will usually optimize it anyway -- *if* it doesn't cause different results, which it very well can *and usually will*.

Write your code correctly -- if you mean to OR, then OR.  If the add-vs-OR ends up being faster, either your compiler will do it for you or you can change it later *after* you've decided whether the potential extra half-nanosecond per iteration is worth the cost in readability and the bugs such a change might cause.

Comment: It's unlikely the compiler can convert one to the other for you - this would require some detailed knowledge of the program's usage of the variables.

Comment: @R..: Usually, but not always.  `(a << 3) + 5` == `(a << 3) | 5` on all two's-complement systems, if `a` is an integer type.  And if you want to check for it, you don't need any knowledge the compiler doesn't already have (the type of `a`, the fact that the three significant bits in `5` will always be 0 from shifting `a` left three bits).  Note that the `5` and `3` would need to be constants in order to make such an optimization possible.  But if they are, it is possible.

Comment: Twos complement has nothing to do with it. The values involved are all positive. (If `a` were negative, `a<<3` has undefined behavior so the compiler need not consider it.)

Comment: This question is tagged C not C#. See 6.5.7 in the C standard.

Comment: @R..: Standard or not, every two's-complement system i've ever heard of ends up doing one of two things -- either it shifts the value and lets the bits fall off, making the third-most-significant bit the new sign bit, or it throws a math error of some kind (usually some sort of overflow error).  If the operation is allowed by the platform and compiler, then the value is known and the equality holds, because of how two's-complement numbers are represented.  Which is why i mentioned that.  But if it bugs you that much, `(a & 0xf8) | 5 == (a & 0xf8) + 5` as well.  The shift was not the point.

Answer (score 6):

Both addition and logical OR are probably performed in a similar part of the ALU of the CPU. There is unlikely to be any measurable performance difference, but this would have be measured in your situation to be certain.

Compilers won't need to bother with this because usually the only way the compiler can know that addition and ORing will give the same result is if the operands are *constants*, and in that case the compiler can simply do the arithmetic at compile time and not even have to generate code for it.

Comment: In theory, the second point ain't necessarily so - for example, given `unsigned char uc1, uc2;` with 8 bit chars, the compiler can see that `uc1 << 8 | uc2` can use either `|` or `+` without affecting the result.

Comment: @caf: Here I would choose `|` over `+` merely because the operator precedence is nicer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In fact, compilers are generally smart enough to make that substitution as appropriate, one way or the other. The term for that kind of optimization is *strength reduction*, and it's the oldest trick in the book.

Answer (score 1):

It's not usually faster and it is wrong mostly unless you know you're "adding" 1 to an even address or value.